# Jasper roo commands problem

Tags: spring-roo

Hi guys I have used springroo for sometime now. Today I came across this promising tool jasperoo for integrating jasper reports into my roo project. However following the pretty much simple instructions on using it doesnt seem to be working.

To start with the osgi installation seems to be too fast and I really doubt if it's successful though if I try removing it after installation the remove command actually runs successfully which I think means the installation was okay.
When I run "jasperoo setup"  I get the following;
Command 'jasperoo setup' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
which means there are some missing dependencies? and which are these ones?
Any help I will highly appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Lawrence,

I'm delighted that you tried jasperoo, but am sorry to hear that you are having trouble with it. I just happened to stumble across your post here.

It sounds like your project does not have the minimum characteristics in place to warrant jasperoo inclusion. Two things you should consider:

1) Run it against the spring roo petclinic example, as described on the project site.

2) If that doesn't work, log a bug report on [jasperoo.digitalface.ca](http://jasperoo.digitalface.ca).

I have been away for a while recovering from surgery, but will be happy to help you through this. Your experience will help make the project better.

Regards,

Waldo Rochow

DigitalFace.ca

Comment: Hey good news, I decided to give one last try and wow, was so lucky, I upgrade STS to version 2.7.1 release and roo 1.1.5 and the jasper commands are now working great, thanks for such a great tool. It's especially useful for us developers in the developing world where most organizations dont have the luxury of putting up large development teams.